# How to create bar graph from qualitative data in R?

Tags: r, character, numeric

I have two columns for olympic data showing the name of the team and one showing the type of medal won by the team. I am trying to calculate the number of medals won by each team in the olympics and then plot a bar graph from the data.

I do not know how to best go about it. The observations for teams repeat as they were extracted from a bigger data set as they show each participants nationality. I want to calculate for each team. However, there are mutiple teams and thus want to do it for the top 10 teams. I thus would also need assistance in ranking them.

Appreciation in this regard will be appreciated.

Comment: Please visit [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Start with `table(team, type-of-medal)`. More information will allow us to provide more specific answers.